# Click to to load/reload datatable

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular, datatables, angular-datatables

After datatable loaded, trying to change pagination from first page to second page.... I need to call the function for every page change, but getting
`Error: this.loadTable is not a function` in console. Please suggest me how to call function `self.loadTable` from `drawCallback` for every pagination click

data table code:

```
      drawCallback: function(s) {
        $('.paginate_button').on('click', () => {
            let self = this;
            self.loadTable();
        });
      }
```

load:

```
loadTable() { console.log("triggered"); };
```

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/passing-pagination-params-and-draw-the-table-jlzztt)

Comment: i'm not sure why you want this line of code `  drawCallback: function(s) {
        $('.paginate_button').on('click', () => {
          // this.loadTable();
        });
      }`

your demo works perfect if you remove this.

Comment: Actually, If I click on pagination buttons like '''first prev next last or number of pages buttons''', need to reload the API with new params like start and end params for loading respective records instead of all records(im trying to do pagination for large set of data)

Comment: This demo API may not change if I clicked the pagination button, but I'm checking console message updating with latest param values, If it works, I will incorporate in my requirement.